# Is there any way to force Mathematica to collect a symbol in a polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, polynomials

Let's say that I have a polynomial like this:

```
a + b + c
```

Is there any way that I can get *Mathematica* to transform it to:

```
a*(1 + b/a + c/a)
```

I found such a manipulation on polynomials very common when deducing equations by hand; however, I have been trying all day and still can not figure out how to make *Mathematica* do this automatically.

Comment: Does `tst = a + b + c; a Expand[tst/a]` not do what you want?

Comment: Oh my god it's so simple. I'm all hooked up on functions like Collect and stuff. Now I just feel stupid. Any way, thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a pattern matching approach (for a bit more advanced users) e.g. :

```
(a + b + c) /. Plus[c___, x_, b___] :> a Expand[Plus[c, x/a, b]]
```

> ```
> a (1 + b/a + c/a)
> ```

or simpler :

```
(a + b + c) /. Plus[x___] :>  a Expand[Plus[x/a]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a better idea. It can be used on the manipulation of complicated expressions.